# VSCode says cannot update preferences on Ubuntu Linux nor find pip

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

ZorinOS Ultimate 15.3 (based on Ubuntu 18.04. 2 LTS)
Python 3.6.9
vscode 1.50.1
pip 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.4.
VSCode says cannot update preferences on Ubuntu Linux nor find pip
I recently installed vscode. I can write and run Python programs in vscode. However, I cannot change preferences. When I try to change the font size, I am told "Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors in it and try again." I also cannot change the version of Python from 2 to 3 for the same reason. This may be why I am told that pip is not available in the selected environment when I try to install Linter pylint.

When I look into the settings.json file where the prefs are said to be stored, I inexplicably find a short program designed to write "Hello World" to the console (either C# or C++). There is nothing else in the file. (~/.config/Code/User/settings.json)

What am I missing?

Comment: probably better to ask in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: @Jimmie Hunk -Have you tried other VSCode environments? And it is recommended that you use the latest version of Python extension and VSCode and try to reload or restart VSCode.

Comment: Thank-you for your suggestion. I am new to VSCode on Linux. I installed VSCode a few days ago and the Python extension yesterday. I wrote my first code in VSCode today without Gtk and it worked. Then I imported the Gtk as I do when working interactively with Python3 in a terminal window. Although it works there, The same code produces an error in VSCode. VSCode 1.50.1, Python extension 2020.10.332292344.  I do not know what you mean by changing environments. I'm new to VSCode and Python. My Unix experience dates back to the early 90's. Sorry to be a noob again at age 72.

Comment: Thank-you, drum. I will try github.

Comment: @Jimmie Hunk -For the python environment of VSCode, you could refer to this link: [Environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments). You could also refer to this [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) to learn more about the use of Python in VSCode.